# codeigniter: single row from the second table in join

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have two tables : `user` and `payment`.

The `user` table have `3 records` and each has `2 payment records` in `payment` table. I want the last payment details of the users, but instead of getting 3 rows, I get only 1 row.

```
$this->db->select('user.*, max(payment.create_at) as last_payment_at');
$this->db->from('user');
$this->db->join('payment','payment.user_id=user.id', 'left');
$this->db->order_by("user.id", "desc"); 
return $this->db->get()->result_object();
```

Comment: try adding $this->db->group_by(user.id); before your return

Comment: @JeremyC. Group by works _before_ the order clause, though

Comment: ah my bad, forgot about that, add it before the order clause then :D

Comment: @JeremyC. yeah, but that won't solve the problem ;)

Comment: you always want to get 3 user's payment ?

Comment: hmm, then I've got nothing unless it's group by (payment.user_id), I don't know why but I have this very strong feeling a group by would be enough here

Comment: can you please add sqlfiddle and you desired output

Comment: i totally forget group by...it work....thank JeremyC and DamienPirsy.....

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('user.*, max(payment.create_at) as last_payment_at'); // you do not have to use max(payment.create_at) as last_payment_at if you are using desc and limit 1
$this->db->from('user');
$this->db->join('payment','payment.user_id=user.id', 'left');
$this->db->order_by("user.id", "desc"); // you can omit this line if you are getting max value

$this->db->limit(1);  // <======= add limit for 1

return $this->db->get()->result_object();
```

Comment: that would still only get him 1 row, he needs to get 1 row for each user (so 3 in total)

Comment: 3 record is an example....it can be any no....i want list of users...any way i got my answer....thank for trying to help......